# GLMM - Aleatory effects in R

Tags: r, random-effects-model, glmm

I have a question if you could help me?
I studied during 2 days (48 hours), 8 times per day (every 3 hours), 3 nests per species (2 species), the number of ants every 3 min that walk by a point. I made this in the 4 seasons of the year. The nests are not the same between seasons.
I am doing a GLMM with one dependent variable with poisson frequency distrubution (number of ants every 3 minutes), two categorical explainatory variables (season and species), and 3 aleatory variables (day, time and nest).
If i´m right day and time are crossing, but i´m not sure if nest are crossing with day and time or nest are "nesting" in the interaction between day and time. I´m not sure about how to express this relation of the aleatory effects in the script.

Its okey the following script??

```
model<- glmer(number ~ sp*season + (1|day:Time:nest), data =datos, family = poisson)
```

.......if are all crossing or

```
model2<- glmer(number ~ sp*season + (1|day:Time/nest), data =datos, family = poisson)
```

......if `nest` is "nested" in the interaction

Comment: Welcome to the site ! Please can you explain what your research hypothesis is ?